# Using an if statement inside a scalar function SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to just return the 10 digit phone number
--I think I did well for removing various non-numeric characters
--What I need help with is removing the '1 '
 from those cases that have the phone number in '1 (xxx)xxx-xxxx' format.

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.CleanPhone',N'FN') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION dbo.CleanPhone
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CleanPhone (@PhoneNumber varchar(200))
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @CleanPhone varchar(200);

SET @CleanPhone =  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim(@PhoneNumber)),'-',''),' ',''),'(',''),')',''),'.','')

--being mysudo code 
IF LEN @CleanPhone > 10 AND Left(@CleanPhone,2) = '1 ' THEN Right(CleanPhone,10)
ELSE @CleanPhone
--end my sudo code 
RETURN @CleanPhone 
END;
GO
```

Comment: After removing all special characters from PhoneNumber field, just return right(CleanPhone,10). No need of IF condition at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since your PhoneNumber has this format:'1 (xxx)xxx-xxxx'

You can go with

```
SET @CleanPhone =  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(ltrim(rtrim(@PhoneNumber)),'-',''),' ',''),'(',''),')',''),'.','')
```

Replace the above statement as

```
SET @CleanPhone =  right(<all your replace goes here>,10)   
RETURN @CleanPhone
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for ease of code maintenance down the road and readability, I would recommend to handle the different conditions by using case statement.

SET @CleanPhone = CASE WHEN condition1 THEN result
                       WHEN condition2 THEN result2
                       ELSE defaullVal
                  END